# how can i get the embedded data from webSite in the flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, web, web-inspector

## How can i get the embaded data from site like this picture

i want to get the Url of this video
how can i access these data from flutter

[the picture is the inspector>network> filter media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtRip.png)

I tried the http and webview doesnt work
these only give me the element
i tried the

```
 ..addJavaScriptChannel(
    'Toaster',
    onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
      );
      },
     )
```

from webview but it doesnt work just give me the log

Comment: is my code not working??